# If one cell IS NOT EMPTY put text on another cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, autofill

I want to insert a text in a cell if another cell isn't empty.
I have a dropdown list in column D.
When a selection is made I want to add the text "Name Surname" to the opposite cell in column F.

I am sharing the Google Sheet sample file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NhMP812BJRazPk9te_wTstoECCMW3TJpd7-8I7rkElI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add one or two examples showcasing your input and expected output(by entering manually) so as for us to get a clear picture of what is expected and all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste following formula in cell `F4` and then copy it to other cells:
`=IF(ISBLANK($D4); ""; "NAME SURNAME")`

Breaking it down:

- `ISBLANC(cell)` function checks if the cell is empty
- `IF(condition; value_if_true; value_if_false)` returns the second or the third argument depending on if the condition holds true.
- `=IF(ISBLANK($D4); ""; "NAME SURNAME")` when cell `$D4` is empty, result is empty string. When `$D4` is not empty, result is `NAME SURNAME`.